# Regex to extract Content-Type

Tags: java, regex, email, email-headers

How can extract the lines with the Content-Type info? In some mails, these headers can be in 2 or 3 or even 4 lines, depending how it was sent. This is one example:

```
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

I tried this regex: `^(Content-.*:(.|\n)*)*` but it grabs everything.

How should I phrase my regex in Java to get only part:

```
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("Content-Type.*?(?=^\\s*\n?\r?$)", 
                                 Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Comment: I tried this but it `find()` returns false. It doesn't find the part.

Comment: @xEnOn I am not sure why it is returning false, here it shows the match http://regexr.com?2v20l

Comment: @xEnOn I updated the regex, can you try it now and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^Content-Type(?:.|\\s)*?(?=\n\\s+\n)");
```

This will match everything which starts with Content-Type until the first completely empty line.

Comment: Thanks! But why do I get a `StackOverFlowError` when I use it this way: `mailContent.replaceFirst("^Content-Type(?:.|\\s)*?(?=\n\\s+\n)", "");`

Comment: @xEnOn I honestly do not know. Can you post a sample at ideone.com?

Comment: I don't even know which part of the code I should paste it as a sample. lol. It's like the whole thing works fine but as long as I change the regex to the one you suggested, I get a StackOverFlowError. So the only problem is the `replaceAll` line. It's weird because the regex you had works when I put it into a regex tester. But I don't know why Java throws that error.

Comment: I think you may need to escape the newlines in the pattern like so: `"^Content-Type(?:.|\\s)*?(?=\\n\\s+\\n)"`

Comment: @ridgerunner Yeah I thought that too but my tool insists that \n is not to be doubly escaped.

Comment: @ridgerunner Escaping the new lines still have the StackOverFlowError. I usually don't escape new lines and they worked too. Do new lines need to be escaped too?

Comment: @xEnOn Can you try with double escapes at \n too?

Comment: @FailedDev I put a sample code on http://ideone.com/lLRg5 Somehow, the StackOverFlowError is thrown when the `find()` function is called.

Comment: @xEnOn Could you try with a smaller mail body? The code you posted does not compile :D

Comment: @FailedDev I am trying it with the exact sample mail content above in the question. In a smaller body, the application hangs. The code I posted isn't complete so it doesn't compile. I don't know where I should start posting my code from because it's kind of long but the main part is where I got the `emailContent` into a String already, and then attempt to do a `replaceFirst()` or `find()` with the regex you suggested. I tried some other random regex and there is no StackOverFlowError. It's weird.

Answer (score 1):

`^Content-(.|\n)*\n\n`
This will match until the blank line.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the relevant RFCs for the exact definition of headers. IIRC in essence you need to consider everything with a linebreak and one or more whitespace characters (eg space, nonbreaking space, tab) to be part of the same header line. I also believe that you should collapse the linebreak and whitespace(s) into a single whitespace element (note: there might be more complex rules, so check the RFCs).

Only if the new line directly starts with a non-whitespace character it is the next header, and if it is immediately followed by another linebreak it ends the header section and starts the body section.

BTW: Why not just use JavaMail instead of reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

This tested script works for me:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
public class TEST
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String subjectString =
            "Content-Type: text/plain;\r\n" +
            "    charset=\"us-ascii\"\r\n" +
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n" +
            "\r\n" +
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,\r\n" +
            "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna\r\n" +
            "aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation\r\n" +
            "ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\r\n" +
            "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit\r\n" +
            "esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint\r\n" +
            "occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia\r\n" +
            "deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\r\n";
        String resultString = null;
        Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile(
            "^Content-Type.*?(?=\\r?\\n\\s*\\n)",
            Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE |
            Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(subjectString);
        if (regexMatcher.find()) {
            resultString = regexMatcher.group();
        } 
        System.out.println(resultString);
    }
}
```

It works for text having both valid: `\r\n` and (invalid but commonly used in the wild): `\n` Unix style line terminations.